# Get enums from byte array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a byte array containing enum values in LE byte order. How would I iterate through such an array in java and cast every 4 bytes to an enum and put it in an array of these enums?
I have a C++ background, so I'm more familiar with pointer arithmetics.
Thank you!

```
public enum MyEnum{
    TAG1(0x0C00),
    TAG2(0x0C01),
    TAG3(0x0C02);

    private final int id;

    MyEnum(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return id;
    }
}


byte[] data = getData(); //  returns  for example '01 0c 00 00 02 0c 00 00' which would I want to interpret as as {TAG2, TAG3}
// this returns a byte array with the enums in LE byte order,
// one after the other

MyEnum[] enums = new MyEnum[data.length / 4];
// now I would copy each enum from the byte array to the enum 
// array, but unsure how to do that in Java
```

Comment: How are you converting `MyEnum` to `byte[]`? Using it's name, order, other property?

Comment: Can you share your `MyEnum` class? How are you storing your byte values as Enum?

Comment: Note that `enum` in Java are full-fledged objects and not just glorified `int` constants as in some other languages, so it's not quite clear what you mean when you say "enum value in LE byte order" and "cast every 4 bytes to an enum". Those phrases make sense if you only see them as an `int` (i.e. their ordinal value), but not from a Java perspective.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yeah that makes sense. I added the enum code for clarification and am seeing myself now that its nothing like a C enum.

Comment: wait... does your `data` contain the Enum ID or just it's index? if it's the enum id, you need a `valueOf(...)` in your enum.

Comment: @Shark It does indeed contain the Values of the IDs. For example `010c0000` would be TAG2. I added comment in the question explaining the content of `data`

Comment: i figured as much. i edited my answer that demonstrates how to get appropriate Enum based on it's internal `id` member

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Map<Integer, MyEnum> all = Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyEnum::getValue, e -> e));
byte[] data = { 0, 0xC, 0, 0, 1, 0xC, 0, 0, 2, 0xC, 0, 0 };
IntBuffer ib = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();
MyEnum[] enums = new MyEnum[data.length / 4];
for (int i = 0; i < ib.capacity(); ++i)
    enums[i] = all.get(ib.get());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(enums));
// -> [TAG1, TAG2, TAG3]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
byte[] data = getData();
// this returns a byte array with the enums in LE byte order,
// one after the other

MyEnum[] enums = new MyEnum[data.length / 4];
// now I would copy each enum from the byte array to the enum 
// array, but unsure how to do that in Java

for (int i = 0; i < enums.length; i++) {
   // read whole enum
   int enumOrdinal = getOrdinalAt(data, i)
   MyEnum currentEnum = MyEnum.values()[enumOrdinal]
   enums[i] = currentEnum
}



private int getOrdinalAt(byte[] data, int enumIndex) {
   return data[enumIndex] || data[enumIndex + 1] || data[enumIndex + 2] || data[enumIndex + 3]
}
```

however, if your `data` is actually containing the enum IDs, such as 0x0c00, 0x0c01 and such, you'll need to expand your enum with something like this:

```
public enum MyEnum{
    TAG1(0x0C00),
    TAG2(0x0C01),
    TAG3(0x0C02);

    private final int id;

    MyEnum(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

       private static Map<Integer, MyEnum> map = new HashMap<>();

        static {
            for(MyEnum enum : MyEnum.values()) {
                map.put(enum.id, enum);
            }
        }

        public static MyEnum valueOf(int enumId) {
            return map.get(enumId);
        }


    public int getValue() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

and once you've read the byte from your `data`, you simply use `MyEnum.valueOf(readThing)` and get the appropriate enum.

e.g. TAG1 for 0x0c00, TAG2 for 0xc01 and so on